# Add certain variables value in between characters in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am currently writing one script which creates an issue in jira based on //TODO comments in my java file. for that, i am using JIRA REST API.

here's my testing script which creates only one issue from a file,

```
#!/bin/bash
file=jira.txt


while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
filename=$(tr -d '\n\r' <<< $(cut -d':' -f1 <<< $line))
summary=$(tr -d '\n\r' <<< $(cut -c4- <<< $(cut -d':' -f3 <<< $line)))

echo -e "\033[1mIssue Name\033[0m = $summary"
echo -e "\033[1mDescription\033[0m = $filename"
key="Project-181"
#key=$(curl -u username:password -X POST --data '{
#    "fields": {
#       "project":
#       {
#          "key": "project"
#       },
#       "summary": "'"$summary"'",
#       "description": "'"$filename"'",
#       "issuetype": {
#          "name": "Task"
#       }
#   }
#}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://JIRA-URL/rest/api/2/issue/ | jq '.key')
echo "key=$key"
sed  -i "/${summary}/s/$/ ${key}/" $filename
    done < "$file"
```

**OUTPUT** of script is,

```
Issue Name = TODO remove hack for my task
Description = /opt/test/testfile.java
key=project-181
```

I purposely commented JIRA REST API part as I don't want to generate new issue every time I ran test script

the output of commented JIRA REST API is as same as a variable declared above that 
 "**key="Project-181**"

Content of **jira.txt** is as follows,

```
/opt/test/testfile.java:211:            // TODO remove hack for my task
```

Now if I ran this script it will run successfully but when I check into **"testfile.java**" I see this,

```
 // TODO remove hack for my task "Project-181"
```

I want something like that to happen,

```
// TODO project-181 Remove hack for my task
```

Any suggestion would be welcome
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `summary="TODO remove hack for my task"`,
if you want to insert `$key` after the "TODO",
change the `sed` line to this:

```
sed  -i "/${summary}/s/TODO \(.*\)/TODO ${key} \1/" $filename
```

Your original `sed` command `"/${summary}/s/$/ ${key}/"` replaced the end of the line `$` with a space followed by `$key`, effectively appending `$key` to the end instead of inserting after "TODO".